# Неверный цвет placeholder в FireFox

Tags: css, css3, input, firefox, placeholder

Проблема в том, что при стилизации placeholder в FireFox он имеет отличный цвет, чем в остальных браузерах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возникает это из-за того, что по умолчанию к стилизации placeholder в Firefox применяется свойство opacity. Чтобы исправить это, нужно добавить вот такие стили:

```
// Fix placeholder color in Firefox 19+ and Firefox 18-
::-moz-placeholder, :-moz-placeholder {
    opacity: 1;
}
```